How to Redirect Based on Form Input and Record Lead in Unbounce
I'm working on an Unbounce landing page and need some help with a form submission script. The goal is to redirect the user to a specific URL based on their input for the company_size field and ensure that the lead is recorded in Unbounce. Here is my current script:


  <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var submitButton = $('#lp-pom-button-43');
    
    submitButton.unbind('click'); 
    
    submitButton.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        
        var companySize = parseInt($('#company_size').val(), 10);
        
      
        var form = $('#lp-pom-form-302');         
        form.submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); 

            var actionURL;

            
            if (companySize === 1 || companySize === 2) {
                actionURL = "https://www.apple.com/";
            } else if (companySize >= 3) {
                actionURL = "https://www.amazon.com/";
            }

          
            $.ajax({
                type: form.attr('method'),
                url: form.attr('action'),
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function() {
                    window.location.href = actionURL;
                }
            });
        });

        
        form.submit();
    });
});
</script>



Requirements:

If the user submits the form and inputs 1 or 2 for company_size, they should be redirected to https://www.apple.com/.
If the user submits 3 or any other number, they should be redirected to https://www.amazon.com/.
Ensure that the lead is recorded in Unbounce before the redirection occurs.

Problem:

If I get the form to redirect correctly, Unbounce doesn't record the lead.

How can I modify this script to ensure that the lead is recorded in Unbounce and that the user is redirected to the appropriate URL based on their input?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Just try to remove form.submit(); it is already done at that point via ajax. When you trigger the submit the browser initiate default action for the form submition. It could duplicate the data and direct the user to an "action" URL with a further routing. To ensure the data in DB check the response in success: function(response){...} method
